# icCube with incremental rows Inserted/Updated/Deleted

Tags: iccube

Our web application manages Employee entries on their own activities, and will show dashboards with isCube.
During the day, all the Employee will have to insert data on web application, and the dashboards will have to show real data, every time that incremental load will be scheduled.
All Employee will insert details of their own activity during the day, what they do, the projects on which they worked, the output they produced (for example how many insurance policy they have done) and so on.
During the day it is possible that Employee will have to update and delete their own datas.
So this is the reason why we would like to have incremental rows Inserted/Updated/Deleted.
Is there a way to do this or we have to schedule Full Load during the night?
Thank you
BR
Maria

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a development questions, better to handle this in the standard icCube forum